# How to build an Akka Streams Source from the Akka Event Stream?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

When `MyActor` receive the `Start` message, it runs an `Akka Stream`, and publish each item received to the `Akka Event Stream`.

```
class MyActor (implicit system: ActorSystem, materialize: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Actor {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Start =>
      someSource
        .toMat(Sink.foreach(item => system.eventStream.publish(item)))(Keep.left)
        .run()
  }
}
```

Now in another block of code I would like to build a `Source` from those items from that event stream, so every item published can be processed in another `Akka Stream`.

How can I do that ?

Just in case it might add more options, note that the other block of code in question is a `Play framework` 's Websocket handler.

Comment: Does this need to be placed into an actor (you can easily run `system.eventStream.publish(item)` outside of an actor)?

Comment: Yes I know, I just extracted that code from a bigger one. It has to do with someSource, the actor will clean resources on Shutdown ... But what about how to consume the Akka event stream in an Akka Stream Source ?

Comment: I mean is there something like `Source.fromAkkaEvent[classOf[Item]]` or can we build that ?

Comment: I think  https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/queue.html might be what you need

Comment: I am still struggling to try to build it using `Source.queue` but, the main issue is that only an Actor can subscribe to the ActorSytem's Event Stream. I really want to do with the Event Stream because I want to keep the publisher and subscriber decoupled. I think I need to find a way to integrate an Actor in the Stream processing.

Comment: Ok, I see. I wouldn't use actor system event bus in this way. Consider using Dynamic stream handling purely https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html#dynamic-fan-in-and-fan-out-with-mergehub-broadcasthub-and-partitionhub

Comment: Thank you so much Ivan, it finally worked with BroadcastHub (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html#using-the-broadcasthub).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work with [BroadcastHub](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html#using-the-broadcasthub) instead, no Akka Event Stream anymore.

My publisher (Which itself is consuming a Source) looks like this:

```
val publisherSource = someSource
  .toMat(BroadcastHub.sink(bufferSize = 256))(Keep.right)
  .run()
```

Then in another code block, I just need a reference to the publisherSource:

```
val subscriberSource = publisherSource
  .map(...) // Whatever
```

You can have as many `subscriberSource` as you want, they will all receive the same items.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If the publisher and subscriber end up de-coupled, what should happen if the publisher produces data faster than the subscriber?

With that said, here's a way to do what you asked for:

```scala
/** Produce a source by subscribing to the Akka actorsystem event bus for a
  * specific event type.
  * 
  * @param bufferSize max number of events to buffer up in the source
  * @param overflowStrategy what to do if the event buffer fills up
  */
def itemSource[Item : ClassTag](
  bufferSize: Int = 1000,
  overflowStrategy: OverflowStrategy = OverflowStrategy.dropNew
)(
  implicit system: ActorSystem
): Source[Item, NotUsed] = Source
  .lazily { () =>
    val (actorRef, itemSource) = Source
      .actorRef[Item](
        completionMatcher = PartialFunction.empty,
        failureMatcher = PartialFunction.empty,
        bufferSize,
        overflowStrategy
      )
      .preMaterialize()

    system.eventStream.subscribe(actorRef, classTag[Item].runtimeClass)

    itemSource
  }
  .mapMaterializedValue(_ => NotUsed)
```